# C function declaration linkage

Tags: c, language-lawyer, linkage, c17

I'm a bit confused with a topic in the *C17 standard*.

In 6.2.2, point 5 you can read:

> If the declaration of an identifier for a **function** has no
> storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it
> were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. [...]

Meaning that it could have either internal or external linkage, depending on other declarations (if any) of that function before that one.

On the other hand, in 6.7.6.3, example 1 (points 16 and 17), you can read:

```
int f(void), *fip(), (*pfi)();
```

> [...]
>
> If the declaration occurs outside of any function, the identifiers
> have file scope and external linkage. [...]

So, it's ok with `pfi` (it's not a function, but a pointer), but what happens then to `f` and `fip`? Isn't that a contradiction? In 6.2.2, it's "as if the **extern** storage-class specifier was present" (which doesn't always mean it will have external linkage), but in 6.7.6.3 it seems the external linkage is given for granted.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** to be more specific, if we have this code in file scope:

```
// One random "previous declaration":
static int f(void);  // declares internal linkage
// Now, the important line, from the initial example:
int f(void);  // Internal linkage? External linkage?
```

6.2.2 states that the second declaration has **internal linkage**.

6.7.6.3 states that the second declaration has **external linkage**.

Comment: A function is not a variable, hence it is not stored in a variable storage area. `pfi` is a variable and so is stored in a variable storage area. `f` and `fip` are declarations of functions returning a [pointer to] `int`.

Comment: I don't follow you. Both quotes seem to me very clear: they both say the identifer has external linkage.

Comment: `extern` tells the compiler "it exists, but maybe not in this compilation unit."

Comment: @bolov not really: "as if extern was used" doesn't necessarily mean it's external: it depends on former declarations.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it's all about identifiers that refer to either a function or an object. They are treated differently. The meaning of `extern` is clear, but the explanations seem to contradict.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie in the standard (6.2.2 and 6.7.6.3).

Comment: Can't see any contradiction. For a function declaration, both state that `extern` is implied. In other words, the function definition may be in another compilation unit.

Comment: @WeatherVane `extern` doesn't always mean external linkage, according to 6.2.2, point 4.

Comment: What of it? There is still no contradiction. Point 4 says that if the linkage was already specified, you can't over-rule it.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's exactly the question: 6.7.6.3 seems to state you can over-rule it, as it says its directly external, not depending on former declarations.

Comment: I still can't see a contradiction. The declarations given in point 16 do not attempt to specify `extern` and point 17 explains what will happen.

Comment: Examples are not normative, may rely on unstated assumptions, may be outright incorrect etc. This example assumes this is the first declaration.

Comment: @WeatherVane check the edit in the question.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That really makes perfect sense, and gives me peace of mind. So the example is quite confusing because the explanation goes on, and says that whether the declaration is in block scope, the linkage depends on former declarations. They should have included that hint in both cases. Thanks!

Comment: It is a nit pick. The point 17 does not contradict, it just overlooks to say *subject to 6.2.2.4* if the attempted specification contradicts a previous declaration. In the question edit, the second declaration will be `static` as 6.2.2.4.

Comment: @WeatherVane yep, you're right. The wording of the text is confusing, as it makes one assumption that does not make in the case of block scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the example code in C 2018 6.7.6.3 16 was intended to be stand-alone code with no prior declarations or the authors of the text in C 2018 6.7.6.3 17 that says “If the declaration occurs outside of any function, the identifiers have file scope and external linkage” overlooked the fact that `f` could have internal linkage due to a prior declaration with `static` and that this new declaration would retain that prior linkage.

As noted in the question, C 2018 6.2.2 5 says “If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`…” Not noted in the question, 6.2.2 4 says “For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration…” And of course we know 6.2.2 3 tells us “If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.”

Thus, if the example code `int f(void), *fip(), (*pfi)();` in a scope in which a prior file-scope `static int f(void);` is visible, then the `f` in the example code has internal linkage.

So C 2018 6.7.6.3 17 is wrong to say `f` necessarily has external linkage unless the example is intended to be stand-alone code with no prior declarations. Further, 6.7.6.3 17 is example text, and [“In ISO standards, examples are without exception non-normative.”](https://www.iso.org/schema/isosts/v1.0/doc/n-asw0.html) The other text quoted above is normative text, so it is binding and the example text in 6.7.6.3 17 is not.